# Querying a column from SQL database using linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am trying to query an SQL database using linq to pick a customer account number, that will enable me to make a reference to other customer details in an entire different oracle database. This is a windows service written in c#

```
 ReferenceDataClassesDataContext dbRef = new ReferenceDataClassesDataContext();
        Reference db = new Reference();
var ids = db.Reference.Select(c => c.referee_Act).ToList();
```

Table name is `"Reference"`, required column is `"referee_Acct"`

Comment: Could you show what have tried?

Comment: am a newbie in programming. Pretty much hvnt done so much, jst been able to create the database base, and also been able to read from excel file am mean't to be reading from. Issue is handling the windows service to select customers acct number from sql table and using same to query an oracle Db to get more customer details

Comment: First you need to create a context. have a look on http://www.asp.net/entity-framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you need to get all AccountNo from table,

```
var ids = from customer in db.Customers select customer.AccountNo;
```